# Jquery animation based on matching strings on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
    $('.rsName').ready(if{($('.companyName').html() == $(this).html()){
        $(this).siblings(".rsDistribution").slideDown('slow', function() {});
    });
```

What I'm trying to do, is check if rsName and companyName are equal. If they are equal, I'd like to slide down the .rsDistribution which is a sibling div of rsName.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an incorrect opening brace

$('.rsName').ready(if **{**  <-----

Also, you need to pass a **function** to the ready handler, which is customarily written:

`$(function() {`

```
 $(function() { 
     if($('.companyName').html() === $('.rsName').html())
        $('.rsName').siblings(".rsDistribution").slideDown('slow');
 });
```

I also took out the callback, since you weren't doing anything with it.

**EDIT**

```
$(function() { 
     $(".rsName").each(function(index, el) {
        if($('.companyName').html() === $(el).html())
           $(el).siblings(".rsDistribution").slideDown('slow');
     }
 });
```

Comment: @crazy - absolutely!  == is just looking for trouble in JavaScript

Comment: the issue is, there are multiple .rsNames on the page, and only one with a sibling I want to slide down. which is why I'm trying to use the "this" selector

Comment: @Elliot - the edit should accomplish that with the each function